# ssh execute command remotely that not exist locally

Tags: ssh, remote-server

Something like

ssh root@host "ls -l"

works fine

But when I'm trying

ssh root@host "showrgst"

I'm getting "command not found". And yes, I don't have showrgst command on the host I'm connected from.

How to solve this?

Comment: 'ssh root@host' and then 'showrgst' works.

Comment: On the remote system, what directory is "showrgst" installed in? How is this directory added to your command path?

Answer (score 1):

you need to install `showrgst` in the remote server and make sure the `PATH` env variable has the path to `showrgst`.

Comment: I have showrgst installed on remote server. I don't have it on any of the hosts I'm connecting from.

Comment: It does not have to be in the host you are trying to connect from. Its enough if its in the remote host. Its not in the path variable as i assume. Try the same command by giving the complete path in the command instead of just the command.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you can locate what executable is for this command

```
   $ which showrgst
```

for example, it is executable script from $HOME/bin/showrgst.
So, you need to copy this file to server by means of scp -

```
  $ scp ~/bin/showrgst youserver.com:/home/username/bin/
```

if this command is executable of some package existing in repositories linux disto, you can install this on your server